# How to get the ylabel function in Matlab working correctly

Tags: matlab, plot, label

So I'm trying to use this code to generate plots:

```
%initialize some variables
antibodies = {'Rel-A','p-Rel-A','IkBa','p-IkBa','A20'};
titles = {'PBS','GOX','TNF','L','M','H'};
x_axis = {'1h','3h','6h'};
y_axis = 'Optical Density';

%create figure
figure('name','Time Course,PBS,Cyt')
for j=1:5,
   subplot(5,1,j)
   errorbar(avg_time_course_data{2}(j,1:3),avg_time_course_error{2}(j,1:3))
   set(gca, 'XTick', 1:6, 'XTickLabel', x_axis)
   title(antibodies(j)) 
   ylabel(y_axis);   
end
```

When I run this script however I get the plots but with no Y label! Does anybody know why?

Comment: you're code is alright, copy & paste and it works as desired. Do you have some more information, maybe also a screenshot?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem. If i use errorbar(rand(1,10), rand(10,1)) in your code, I do get the expected ylabel at each subplot.However, you seem to want to have 6 xticks but only offer 3 values to be set there, so they are repeating. Maybe this is not what you want.

Comment: Okay so I have identified that I have a 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' error when I add the ylabel that does not occur when I plot it without. Does that help you in visualizing the problem? Also, with the xTick bit - would I just use set(gca, 'XTick', 1:3, 'XTickLabel', x_axis) instead? because it doesn't seem to make a difference to the plot. Cheers

Comment: does it actually plot all 5 subplots? or does it stop after the first one?

Comment: It plots all 5 plots exactly how I want them, but without a y axis label

Comment: 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' - check you haven't shadowed the function `ylabel` with a variable named `ylabel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some lines in your code. I also tested with `errorbar(rand(1,10), rand(10,1))`.

```
%initialize some variables
antibodies = {'Rel-A','p-Rel-A','IkBa','p-IkBa','A20'};
titles = {'PBS','GOX','TNF','L','M','H'};
x_axis = {'1h','3h','6h'};
y_axis = 'OD'; % I made the string shorter, because it was overlapping the other ylabel on my screen.

%create figure
figure('name','Time Course,PBS,Cyt')
for jj=1:5,
   subplot(5,1,jj)
   errorbar(rand(1,10), rand(10,1))
   set(gca, 'XTick', 1:6, 'XTickLabel', x_axis)
   title(antibodies(jj)) 
   set(get(gca,'YLabel'), 'String', y_axis); % The code now use a different method for setting the ylabel string.   
end
```

Let me know if it helps you.